# PHP Curl and Firebase Post IDs

Tags: php, curl, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Does anyone know a way to remove post ids from Firebase posts or to customize them to be a single key like "word"

```
 testproject-60f4d
    dictionary
     terms
      -KgjrTqL99czkMu7DnMS
        - word
         - wordName: "Alpha"
         - wordVal: "001"
      -KgjrU19IVxlFkPbAbwR
      -KgjrU7a3apTYFYKGj77
      -KgjrUEFJj10TJl0pxCM
      -KgjrUMyZBPS07FWwAbU
```

I want the following layout

```
 testproject-60f4d
    dictionary
     terms
        - word
         - wordName: "Alpha"
         - wordVal: "001"
        - word
         - wordName: "Bravo"
         - wordVal: "002"
        - word
         - wordName: "Charlie"
         - wordVal: "003"
        - word
         - wordName: "Delta"
         - wordVal: "004"
```

Comment: You are asking for an array instead of a collection/map/dict/hash. See https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html